# iCalendar Recurrence Rule to Human Readable Text - Localization for CJK Languages

Tags: localization, icalendar, rrule, rfc5545, ekrecurrencerule

So far, all online libraries that I've found, offer functionality for **converting Rrule strings to human readable strings** for the **English language only**.

I tried to modify the code from the [Rrule Package (Flutter)](https://github.com/JonasWanke/rrule/tree/main/lib/src/codecs/text) (which is mainly based on [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule)) for adding support for CJK languages, but the result doesn't satisfy me yet and I think I might need a slightly different approach.

Looking at the *BigTech* implementations: Google doesn't show anything (at least in their calendar app) and Google translation does an awful job with translating more complex recurrence rules from English to e.g. Korean), Microsoft and Samsung calendars support only very simple Recurrence Rules, Apple seems to have one of the best solutions in their calendar.

So I was wondering if there is any open source/accessible code for **converting Rrule strings to human readable Strings for CJK languages** that I could refer to? The more complex recurrence rules are supported, the better.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: @memical nope :( not yet